# Passing PHP Array into Javascript

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have an Array like below in PHP

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Mink7',
        'about' => 'Creative Design agency',
        'logo' => null,
        'lat' => '13.004870000000',
        'lng' => '77.576686084656'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'name' => 'Bakasura',
        'about' => 'Live 2 Eat',
        'logo' => null,
        'lat' => '13.005643569006',
        'lng' => '77.577485382942'
    )
)
```

What have i done.
I load the Function in the Header and have written the following in the body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        var startups = <?php echo json_encode($startups); ?>;
        $.each(startups, function(key, val) {
            markMe(val.lat, val.lng, val.name, val.description, val.logo);
        });
});
</script>
```

I am getting the following error

> markMe is not defined
>
> markMe(val.lat, val.lng, val.name, val.description, val.logo);

Javascript File that is attached to HEAD.

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function () {
    var map = new GMaps({
        div: '#map',
        lat: 13.00487,
        lng: 77.576729,
        zoom: 13,
    });

    /*
    GMaps.geolocate({
        success: function (position) {
            map.setCenter(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('Geolocation failed: ' + error.message);
        },
        not_supported: function () {
            alert("Your browser does not support geolocation");
        },
        always: function () {
            //alert("Done!");
        }
    });
    */

    map.addControl({
        position: 'top_right',
        text: 'Geolocate',
        style: {
            margin: '5px',
            padding: '1px 6px',
            border: 'solid 1px #717B87',
            background: '#fff'
        },
        events: {
            click: function () {
                GMaps.geolocate({
                    success: function (position) {
                        map.setCenter(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert('Geolocation failed: ' + error.message);
                    },
                    not_supported: function () {
                        alert("Your browser does not support geolocation");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    map.addMarker({
        lat: 13.00487,
        lng: 77.576729,
        title: 'Lima',
        icon: "http://i.imgur.com/3YJ8z.png",
        infoWindow: {
          content: '<p>HTML Content</p>'
        }
    });

    function markMe(lat, lng, name, description, logo){
        map.addMarker({
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng,
            title: name,
            icon: "http://i.imgur.com/3YJ8z.png",
            infoWindow: {
              content: description
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look for [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php) in PHP, and use `JSON.parse` in JavaScript (or a library like `jQuery.parseJSON` if you need broad browser support)

-- after update

instead of
function markMe(lat, lng, name, description, logo){

do:
markMe = function (lat, lng, name, description, logo){

that's because a function declared in a function is not availlable outside that function

Comment: yeah i tried that method.. but i am getting the following error 

    markMe is not defined

    markMe(val.lat, val.lng, val.name, val.description, val.logo);

Answer (score 1):

Before answering id like to point out that i am making some assumptions.

1. I assume that the above array is in php
2. I assume that the below function is javascript

if that is the case you can just put array references into the javascript function and it will work.

Im guessing at your data mappings and I would suggest that a better method would be to build the whole function up by php and output it to the screen with a method call to make the code easier to read/understand

However with a guess at your mappings and to test to see if the code works before creating a method call i would run with something like this as a first stab.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
 foreach($array as $point)
 {
?>
 {
 map.addMarker({
  lat: <?php print $point["lat"]; ?>,
  lng: <?php print $point["lng"]; ?>,
  title: <?php print $point["name"]; ?>,
     icon: <?php if(!is_null($point["logo"]){ print $point["logo"];} ?>,
     infoWindow: {
       content: <?php print $point["about"]; ?>
     }
 });
 <?php } ?>
</script>
```

Thanks

Nicholas

Comment: with $.each function i am able to do the iteration. But it says the function is missing

Comment: sorry my answer was given before the question was edited and it was not apparent you were making JSON calls.

Comment: i am not making json calls still. I am converting the Array into json and assigning it to a variable

Comment: is the top array in php or js?

Comment: PHP.. which i am json_encoding in the next step. Edited my Question to show the clarity

Comment: just to check is the markme function included and loaded before making the call to it?

Comment: can you call the markme function by placing dummy data into it?

Comment: I think this thread is better removed to chat. I have recently completed a project doing similar things to what you are trying to achieve in c#

Comment: Nope damn.. I am not able to call the function with dummy data. I think the scope of the function is not available globally. I have attached the js file also in my question. Sure lets move it into Chat

Comment: Nicholas King has only 11 reputation, not yet enough to chat :(

Comment: i can post my $.each function which was appending posts to a postit board from a json collection

Comment: thank would really help me. Thanks a lot :) i think the problem here is more to do with the scope of variables than passing the content. As console log shows the content properly

Comment: can i email you my code? it will come from my personal email nicholas.king[at]freshxen[dot]co[dot]uk?